# Color of status bar on Xcode 9.3 not changing despite overriding

Tags: ios, swift

I've used the following code:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

It does work on my initial view controller scene, but it does not work on any other ones.

I've put the same function on each viewcontroller's Swift file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any updations in `info.plist` file?

Comment: I haven't done any updates

Comment: Perform the changes as stated [in answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49869837/988169).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can change the info.plist the row `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set it to `NO`
2. Then put this line of code in your `appDelegate.swift` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

   `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

When you override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in a viewcontroller then it will work for that controller. But if you want to change whole application status bar style then put this line of code in you `AppDelegate` class.

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work, it still shows black text. There must be some setting I messed up when I previously tried to do this.

Comment: If you want to continue manually setting the style of the status bar, continue doing what you're doing, but you'll need to add the following key to your info.plist file with a value of NO.

View controller-based status bar appearance

Or, if you want to continue to use view controller based status bar appearance, instead of setting the application's statusBarStyle, override the preferredStatusBarStyle property in each view controller for which you'd like to specify a status bar style.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the below changes to keep the status bar of color white.

- Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in info.plist = No
- In AppDelegate, set `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`

Answer (score 0):

1.Change in info.plist the row View controller-based status bar appearance and set it to NO

2.Change in appDelegate.swift in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```